# Which Connection String is correct?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, connection-string

i write a program with mvc and entity framework.
i have problem with connection string.

my host say your connection string must be like follow:

```
Server=sql2005.yourdomain.com,1430;Database=databaseName;Uid=userName;Password=password;
```

and connection string in my program is:

```
<add name="sbiEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.modelCompany.csdl|res://*/Models.modelCompany.ssdl|res://*/Models.modelCompany.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\sbi.mdf;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

how change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An EF connection string is divided into several parts divided by a semicolon (;).

- The first part is the model metadata, this is autogenerated from your edmx file.
- The second part is the provider EF should use to communicate with your storage.
- The third part is the provider connection string which is your current connection string (line wrapped for readability):

  ...provider connection string=`&quot;`data source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;
  attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\sbi.mdf;
  integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework`&quot;`

  The text between the two `&quot;` is your current connection string and is the one that should be replaced. Be aware to keep the MultipleActiveResultSets=True, and switch the App=EntityFramework with an application name that reflects your application for easier diagnostic.

Comment: change connection string but dont work and this error diplay : **Sorry, an error occurred while processing your request.**

Comment: That was a strange error. Is there any inner exceptions to that message? Can you provide your modified connection string?

Comment: only display that. **<add name="sbiEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.modelCompany.csdl|res://*/Models.modelCompany.ssdl|res://*/Models.modelCompany.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string= &quot; Server=sql2005.alipanahi2.ir,1430;Database=4373_sbi;Uid=4373_userdb;Password=12345; MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework; &quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />** .another offer my host for connection string is **Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data source=sql2005.yourdomain.com,1430;Initial catalog=databaseName;User Id=userName;Password=password;**

Comment: Cannot se anything wrong with that... That one should work... Are you sure that your configuration is correct and that your server is accessible?

Comment: thank you (for _connection string_), find that, my table name was [dbo][company] but in host database was [company] !!!

Answer (score 1):

Entity Framework having a special type of connection string which have CSDL, SSDL, MSL and your original connection string.

Conceptual schema definition language (CSDL): This section describe your conceptual model of EDMX file.

Storage schema definition language (SSDL): This section describe the database schema model of EDMX file.

Mapping specification language (MSL): This section is for the mappings of the two world (CSDL and SSDL).

EF actually get the CSDL, SSDL and MSL file names from the connection string.